# Why does TypeScript think this immutable type is an index type when the variable is explicitly type hinted?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

Given the following structs:

```
enum SelectorTypes {
    Attribute = 'attribute',
    Class = 'class',
    Id = 'id',
    Type = 'type',
    CSS = 'css',
}

/*
 * Interface for defining shorthand CSS selector key-value-type thruples (k, v, t) and an
 * optional attribute (a) name.
 */
interface Selector {
    // key (name)
    k: string
    // value
    v: string
    // type
    t: SelectorTypes
    // optional attribute name
    a?: string
}

type KeyUnion<T extends readonly Selector[]> = T[number]['k']
```

And the following helper:

```
const CSSFactory = <T extends KeyUnion<readonly Selector[]>>(
    selectors: readonly Selector[],
    defaultAttribute: string = 'data-testid',
): { [key in T]: string } => {
    // returns object with well defined, strongly typed key value pairs
}
```

I get different behaviour from the TS server depending on whether or not I explicitly define the selectors array type.

This works:

```
const selectors = [
    { k: 'base', v: 'hub_toolbar', t: SelectorTypes.Id },
    { k: 'windowManager', v: 'window-manager-toolbar', t: SelectorTypes.Class },
] as const

// good: toolBarSelectors is an explicit KVP object with { base: string, windowManager: string }
const toolBarSelectors = CSSFactory<KeyUnion<typeof selectors>>(selectors)
```

This doesn't work:

```
const selectors: readonly Selector[] = [
    { k: 'base', v: 'hub_toolbar', t: SelectorTypes.Id },
    { k: 'windowManager', v: 'window-manager-toolbar', t: SelectorTypes.Class },
] as const

// bad: toolBarSelectors is an object with an index type signature [x: string]: string
const toolBarSelectors = CSSFactory<KeyUnion<typeof selectors>>(selectors)
```

I understand that `as const` is shorthand for declaring the object's own shape as it's type. What I would like to do is tell TS that each member of the `selectors` array must be a `Selector` object, i.e. each object should have the shape: `{ k: string, v: string, t: SelectorTypes, a?: string }` - so that trying to add something else would show a type error - but still have TS understand that the resulting object returned by the `CSSFactory` is an object with well defined properties and values.

Is this possible? And why doesn't it work the way I have tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you explicitly type `const selectors: readonly Selector[]`, then that's what `typeof selectors` will be. It does not matter whether you assign a const expression to the variable or not (as long as it's a `readonly Selector[]` expression).

What you're looking for is the [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator):

```
const selectors = [
    { k: 'base', v: 'hub_toolbar', t: SelectorTypes.Id },
    { k: 'windowManager', v: 'window-manager-toolbar', t: SelectorTypes.Class },
] satisfies readonly Selector[];
```

---

Btw, to avoid having to pass a type parameter to the `CSSFactory` helper function, and have it inferred instead, you should make it generic over its parameter not over its return type:

```
const CSSFactory = <T extends readonly Selector[]>(
    selectors: T,
//             ^
    defaultAttribute: string = 'data-testid',
): { [key in KeyUnion<T>]: string } => {
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^
    …
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the satisfies operator does indeed make the TS server hint correctly when there are missing properties from `Selector` objects insides the `selectors` array - but to keep TS from inferring the array elements as indexed (i.e. as `[x: string]: string`) I had to keep the `as const` and have the satisfies operator on it's own line. Otherwise this is the correct answer and what I was looking for, thanks!